# How to limit the number of comment a user can post?

Tags: 7, comments

I have a content type where users can post reviews or comments. 
I want to achieve this with the comment module and not by creating another content type and using node reference.

**So I want to limit the number of comment a user can post per node for a specific type of content type.**

Again I also have other content types where I have given the users the option of commenting on article, and that can have multiple comments and replies.

Can anyone suggest me how to achieve this?

Can I do it through rules(I haven't tried yet)?

Answer (score 2):

You could add a validate handler to the comment form

e.g, something like:

```
/**
 * hook_form_FORM_ID_alter
 */
function MODULE_form_comment_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, &$form_id) {
  $form['#validate'][] = 'MODULE_comment_form_validate';
}

/**
 * Validate comment form submission
 */
function MODULE_comment_form_validate($form, &$form_state){
  $node = node_load($form_state['values']['nid']);
  if(isset($node->type) && $node->type = 'targetted_type'){
    $account = user_load_by_name($form_state['values']['name']);
    if(!empty($account->uid)){
      // Get comment count for this node type
      $query = db_select('comment', 'c');
      $query->join('node', 'n', 'n.nid = c.nid');
      $query->condition('c.uid', $account->uid);
      $query->condition('n.type', 'targetted_type');
      $query->countQuery();
      $comments = $query->execute()->fetchField();
      if($comments > variable_get('max_comments_targetted_type', 3)){
        form_set_error('name', 
          t('You are only allowed to post %max comments on this type of content.', array('%max' => variable_get('max_comments_targetted_type', 3))));
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: In this case the problem is that the user can see the comment form and post it but comment will refused by validation function. I think this answer will be fine if complemented with wolverine answer: alter the node_view to unset the form if user can't post

Answer (score 1):

If you want to allow the user to comment only once then you can look into [Onecomment](https://www.drupal.org/project/onecomment) module.

But if you want to use more complex logic then you can implement `hook_node_view()` and put your logic there and then unset the comment form from the `$node->content`. You can refer the code of `Onecomment` module.

Comment: In this case the problem is that a user could manage to send more post that allowed if, for example, oad several pages with the comment form. This can be fixed adding a custom validation function as David Thomas says in his answer.

Comment: That logic is already there in `Onecomment` module, if you are writing custom module then you have to do that as well.